# For selling items in a game, should the shop and item tables be merged?

Tags: postgresql, performance, database-design, normalization, relational-theory

I'm developing a game that uses a Postgres database. In the game players can have many different items, and each player can have multiples of an item (example: 200 apples). My `item` table currently looks like this (example data):

```
item_id | user_id | quantity | created_at
```

Now, I want to also add the ability for players to sell items to each other. So, players will be able to list items for sale, and we also need the ability to query items of a certain id that are for sale (and view an individual's shop). I thought of two ways to do this.

**Method 1:** Have a separate `shop` table and `item` table, like this:

```
item table:
item_id | user_id | quantity | created_at


shop table:
item_id | user_id | quantity | created_at | price
```

My issue with this is that a player could have 10 apples, but only want to sell 5 of them. So I suppose I would have to do some sort of transaction where you decrement 5 from the quantity (and remove the row if quantity reaches 0 from this action), and then create a new row in the `shop` table with a quantity of 5 (or increment if that item is already being sold)

**Method 2:** Merge the two tables

```
item table:
item_id | user_id | quantity | created_at | price | sell_quantity
```

In this case, `price` would either be nullable (item is not for sale) or perhaps the price of 0 would mean it wasn't for sale. In addition, we would have another column for how many are being sold. The issue with this is it seems like a lot of wasted space. I imagine most people aren't going to sell most of their items, so having those two columns be empty in 99% of cases seems wasteful.

However, the two table approach *also* seems wasteful, because we are duplicating `item_id` and `user_id` which we wouldn't have to do if the tables were merged.

Is there a better way to do this that I am missing? Both of these solutions seem suboptimal. And if there isn't, which of these is preferable?

Comment: NULL columns don't take much space, and duplicating two id columns for 1% of the rows doesn't either.  I don't think the decision should be made based on those considerations.  Can they keep using the item while it is listed for sale, or do they have to leave it at a consignment shop or something?

Comment: Hmm, good question. I think the gameplay logic I want to have is that the item cannot be used while it is listed in their shop. That is, the item is "moved" from the player's inventory to their shop.

Comment: You have answered your own question

Comment: It's that simple, huh? Haha, alright, thanks!